# Grouping similar entites in DB

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, relational-database

I am designing a MySQL DB table for my project, I am having trouble deciding which approach is better.

The table is called a `Services` table, and there is also a concept of `Package` which is nothing but a selected group of `Services`.

Now, my question is should I treat Package services as an independent entity and have `PackageService` table and `PackageService_Service` relationship table?

OR

Should I treat `Package` service as just another service in `Service` table with a "package" flag set to true? If this is a better approach, then how and where do I mention which services come under this `Package` service?

Comment: plz post your table structure for better understanding

Comment: Doesn't seem like a package is a service. just a grouping element, correct?

Comment: @BobfCali People can either opt for an individual service or a package (which has selected services at different price) but a packaged service is shown to them as a service and is fixed, as in user can't create their own package by choosing a bunch of services.

Comment: And I should also be able to suggest packages if the user selected an individual service and that same service is offered in any of the existing packages.

Comment: Seems more like a many-many.

Comment: @BobfCali Yes, it is indeed. But there are already Service_cost, service_duration, hospital_service, doctor_service relationship tables which link service with different entities. Now if I create a new entity called PackageService then I will have to write all these relationship tables for the new entity!

Comment: The package would be a summation of the individuals in some respects and it would be a totally separate product in other respects.  Those other relationships are implied by the package service relationship.  The problem is when the a rvices have different relations like two hospitals.  Then a decision has to be made to determine which hospital will belong to this package.  So yes you may have to do that if the business needs it.  Otherwise you need a new service definition for each package.

Answer (score 0):

One package can have many services and one service can be in many packages.

It should be a Service_Package table.

Also, I went through the comments. This service_package can be *joined* with service_cost etc table with service_id as the join column. Then you will have a *joined* set of records for a package with package_id, service_id, cost, service_duration and so on in case you need all this info together. Or, you can join package_service with individual tables such as service_cost separately as per the business use cases.

Once you have the *joined* set of records, you have the data you need, then you can use aggregate functions to do any synthesis of that data or display these records as is.